# Site not scrolling on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, scrollview

```
const Membership = () => {
  const [showNavbar, setShowNavbar] = useState(false);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => setShowModal((state) => !state);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (window.scrollY >= 100) {
        setShowNavbar(true);
      } else {
        setShowNavbar(false);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="bg-bienBg">
      {showNavbar && (
        <Navbar path="/membership-form" name="Apply for Membership" />
      )}

      {showModal && <MoreInfoModal toggleModal={toggleModal} />}
        <MembershipServices />
        <MembershipPlan toggleModal={toggleModal} />
        <MembershipFooter />
     </div>
  );
};

export default Membership;
```

The feature where the navbar appears hidden until the page is scrolled on works perfectly on large screens (1024 px) and above, but when it gets to smaller screens, the scrollbar disappears, making the page not scrollable. It's like the page is playing hide-and-seek with us!

Comment: It looks like a media query problem. Check your media queries with (max-width:1024px) and look for **overflow** tag in them.